# Spacy not getting entities from text

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

Have the following python code with spacy:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc = nlp("NEXT EXPEDITION ON 05/06/2015")
print(doc.text)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent, ent.label_)
```

But it only results in doc.text being printed, there is no entity in doc:

```
doc.text = NEXT EXPEDITION ON 05/06/2015
```

Anyone can help me to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you expecting ?